# Hint for Dini’s condition of piecewise function at zero

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

**(Only hints, please)**

Let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^3+1 & x >0\\
0 & x = 0\\
x^2-1 & x <0
\end{cases}$$

I am trying to show this function satisfies Dini’s condition at $x=0$. In our case here, that is there exists $\delta >0$ such that
$$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}dt$$ is finite.

Naturally, if $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then Dini’s condition holds. Further, if even the right and left derivatives exist, we may conclude.

However, while certainly on $x>0$, $f’(x)=3x^2 \to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$ coincides with the behavior on $x<0$, with $f’(x)=2x\to 0$ as $x\to 0^-$, we also can compute by definition
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{h^3+1}{h}=\infty,$$
no? So, the right hand derivative does not exist at $x=0$? Now, if I try to compute the integral directly to show Dini’s condition holds for some $\delta$, I get some blow ups about any neighborhood of zero I take.

So my question is, since I assume this problem was correctly written, what am I doing wrong and what are some hints to proceed?

**Edit:**
Here is my direct calculation.
With $x=0$ and $f(0)=0$, the relevant integral expression becomes
$$\int_{-\delta}^\delta \frac{f(t)}{t}dt.$$
We split this up and use the piecewise definition of $f$, to get
$$\int_{-\delta}^0 \frac{t^2-1}{t} dt+\int_0^\delta \frac{t^3+1}{t}dt$$
$$=\int_{-\delta}^0 t-\frac{1}{t}  dt+\int_0^\delta t^2+\frac{1}{t}dt.$$
But both of these integrals diverge, since $\int \frac{1}{t}=\log |t|+C$ blows up as we approach zero, no? Or am I being too quick to judge?

**Edit 2**
My professor said to consider principal value integration and use the fact that $1/t$ is an odd function hence the integral over $(-\delta, \delta)$ vanishes in the principal value sense. This I understand and can prove. However, I do not see how to clinch the problem with this hint, unless the piecewise function was changed to $f(x)=x^2+1$ on $x<0$. For otherwise, when I split up the integral and isolate the integrand $1/t$, I cannot recombine them into an integral over the whole interval because of a sign difference.

Comment: I think you should go with the direct calculation. Want to share in more detail where you think it goes wrong?

Comment: I guess that $$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}dt$$ should be $$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}dx.$$

Comment: @podiki I added my direct calculation attempt. Let me know what you think!

Comment: @xpaul My professor's lecture slides integrate with respect to $t$ and further Dini's condition is stated to hold at a pre-given point $x$, so I am not too convinced that switching the integration-variable is the right thing to do here...but maybe.

Comment: @NapD.Lover I deleted my comment because I don't think what I said is true. It does look like the integral you have diverges for any $\delta >0$.

Comment: @podiki yeah I was just about to edit that it still gave me a divergent term. I suppose I might have to email the professor.

Comment: @podiki so just to follow up, in case you were curious: my professor said to think in terms of principal values of integrals and use the fact that $1/t$ is an odd function, so the integral of $1/t$ over $(-\delta, \delta)$ vanishes in the P.V. sense. Now that fact I can prove but I still can’t seem to clinch the conclusion to the problem itself…